# ¿Cómo seleccionar registros sin repetición de un campo específico de tabla con LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

***¿Cómo sería el equivalente de este método usando LINQ?***

Mi código:

```
public List<string> GetIdsCuentaGeneral()
        {
            var idsCuentaGeneral = new List<string>();
            string strCnx = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMv2_Cliente_ConnectionString"].ToString();
            string query = "SELECT IdCuentaGeneral FROM A_Conta_Apunte GROUP BY IdCuentaGeneral ORDER BY IdCuentaGeneral ASC";
            SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(strCnx);
            using (cnx)
            {
                cnx.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnx);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (read.Read())
                    idsCuentaGeneral.Add(read.GetString(0));

                cnx.Close();
            }
            return idsCuentaGeneral;
        }
```

Escribí este código pero todavía le falta … porque me devuelve una lista pero cada elemento contiene la palabra key y el signo igual , algo así ( **key = VT00432**) y yo solo necesito  el **IdCuentaGeneral** es decir **VT00432**

```
 public List<string> GetIdCuentaGeneral()
        {
          var t = (from aca in db.A_Conta_Apunte
                     group aca by aca.IdCuentaGeneral into ids
                     orderby ids.Key
                     select new { ids.Key }).AsEnumerable().ToList();

            List<string> idx = new List<string>();
            foreach (var x in t)
            {
                idx.Add(x.ToString ());
            }
            return idx;   
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mostrar los resultados debes aplicar dos **ciclos foreach**, uno que recorra las llaves de agrupación y otro que recorra los elementos dentro de estas llaves de agrupación:

```
 public List<string> GetIdCuentaGeneral()
 {
      var consulta = (from a in db.A_Conta_Apunte
                      group a by a.IdCuentaGeneral into grupo
                      orderby grupo.Key
                      select grupo);  
     
        List<string> idx = new List<string>();

        foreach (var grupo in consulta)
        {
            foreach(var g in grupo )
            {
               idx.Add(g.ToString());
            }                
        }

        return idx;            
    }
```

Pero para tu caso en específico te recomiendo este método:

```
 public List<string> GetIdCuentaGeneral()
 {
      return (from a in db.A_Conta_Apunte
              orderby a.idCuentaGeneral
              select a.idCuentaGeneral.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();                      
 }
```

De esta forma selecciono todos los elementos haciendo un resumen de los mismos a través del **método Distinct** que evita que hallan elementos duplicados, en este caso el **método Distinct** funciona igual que el **groupby.**